# Do not handle button click when caused by key press

Tags: c#, wpf, mouseevent

I have a WPF project. In this project at some point I'm dynamically making button in code behind like this:

```
private Button makeButton()
{
     Button b = new Button();
     b.Width = 24;
     b.Height = 19;
     b.Click += ButtonClick;
    
     return b;
}
```

Where the ButtonClick is:

```
public void ButtonClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
     // Do stuff...
}
```

Sometimes happen the event handler is called on pressing enter, even when button is not focused.
So my question is how can I disable to handle this event when it's caused by enter.

Tnaks you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem. Using [PreviewMouseLeftButtonUp](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.uielement.previewmouseleftbuttonup?view=netcore-3.1) event fixed my problem. It will not hire when you use `enter` button

Comment: Thank you for answer. Yes this could be possible solution, but the problem is the handler is called when the mouse button is up, even if cursor is not on button. Similar to the problem with PreviewLeftMouseButtonDown, it's still not a classic mouse click.

Answer (score 0):

It is probably getting focused before you press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Anyway, you could try to set the `Focusable` property to `false`:

```
b.Focusable = false;
```

Also make sure that you don't set the `IsDefault` property to `true`.

Comment: Thank you for answer. I set Focusable to false and even IsDefault to false but the problem still occurs.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how this is happening with the button not focussed. Maybe this is logical rather than keyboard focus.

It'd have been nice to have a minimal reproduction.

Two things you can try.

1)

Eat the enter key just in case the keypress is somehow going to the button by using the previewkeydown event on the button. Marking the event as handled will stop the keydown event from firing so no enter will reach the button if it's somehow logically receiving the keypress.

```
        b.PreviewKeyDown += (o, e) =>
        {
            if (e.Key == Key.Enter) e.Handled = true;
        };
```

2. 

Set IsDefault="False" on the buttons in case they're somehow being set as default.